# How to get a data from an html tag using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an HTML page, and inside one of its tags, I have a hard coded text (similar to a json format). I want to get this text and save it in an AngularJS scope variable, that I can parse and use dynamically in an other page.

So I want to know if is it doable with AngularJS? If yes, do you have any indication, which directive I can use?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not put it into your js file directly? e.g. main controller scope or rootScope.

Comment: Because it's an other app that generate this html page for me, with a lot of information. And I don't have control on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to get the value of your element. Try this:

In your HTML:

```
<span id="foo">FOOFOOBAR</span>
```

In your angular controller :

```
$scope.foo = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#foo' ) );
```

or in a classic JS :

```
var foo = document.getElementById('soap-response').innerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have id, you can do this
angular.element(document.querySelector('#id')).html() and put it on scope

Answer (score 0):

Get your "hard coded text" with Dom Manipulation in your angular controller.

Then transform it to an object with [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/JSON/parse)